# How to make onChange event listener in declarative component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is the declarative component

```
export default function InputDialogContent(props: InputDialogContentProps) {

  const [textAreaValue, setTextAreaValue] = useState<string>("");

  return (
    <div>
      <DialogContent>
        <TextField
          autoFocus
          margin="dense"
          id="name"
          label={props.inputLabel}
          type={props.inputType}
          fullWidth
        />
      </DialogContent>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am using it in another component.
What I want to do is I wanna alert something every time I type something inside the text area

```
    import InputDialogContent from './shared/InputDialogContent';
    
    export class SettingsMenu extends Component<
      SettingsMenuProps,
      SettingsMenuState
    > {
      constructor(props: SettingsMenuProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          settingsAnchorElement: null,
          currentDialog: null,
        };
      }
    
      render() {
         return (
            <InputDialogContent inputLabel="Email Address" 
             inputType="email" 
             onChange={(ev: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>): void => alert(ev.target.value)}/>
        )}
```

but I am getting the error when hovering on the onChange in the compiler. I know that the error occurs because the export component itself is not a textarea. Someone help, please

```
    {
        "message": "Type '{ inputLabel: string; inputType: string; onChange: (ev: ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InputDialogContentProps'.\n  Property 'onChange' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InputDialogContentProps'.",
    }
```

Comment: Seems like `InputDialogContent` expects no `onChange` attribute. You may need to add that attribute or it might be called something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component is missing the `onChange` event, you need to forward it to your text area:

```
export default function InputDialogContent(props: InputDialogContentProps) {

  const [textAreaValue, setTextAreaValue] = useState<string>("");

  return (
    <div>
      <DialogContent>
        <TextField
          autoFocus
          margin="dense"
          id="name"
          label={props.inputLabel}
          type={props.inputType}
          onChange={props.onChange}
          fullWidth
        />
      </DialogContent>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Additionally, you need to make sure that `InputDialogContentProps` includes a property `onChange` of the appropriate type.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me if you are controlling the TextField value inside the child component or you want to pass the value from its parent, but you could try this:

```
    <TextField
      autoFocus
      margin="dense"
      id="name"
      label={props.inputLabel}
      type={props.inputType}
      value={textAreaValue}
      onChange={ev=>{ setTextAreaValue(ev.target.value); props.onChange(ev); }}
      fullWidth
    />
```